# How to run multiple test in a single session - Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, ui-automation

I am working on a test automation for a webapp that takes several time to login. I would like to create a automation that can run multiple test in a single session without the need of login in and out constantly(which will reduce the time running the automation in more than 1h 30m every day).

I thought about running the login, wrapping the tests in a loop (so I can select the tests that will be runned) and logout once everything is completed. However I don't know how I can do that, how to select and execute the tests that will be run from Visual Studio, if it would still be possible to run test in parallel, different types of users, etc.

Is this something possible to do? Any tool that may help with this? Or if you have succeeded... How?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and [mcve]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.  Unfortunately, your question is too broad.  But it seems like you want to look for a test harness with setup and teardown hooks (which is a common feature).  I'd try googling for a C# option.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will make sure to read the links you sent. I was conscious I wasn't very specific but I just had that question in my mind, I couldn't find anything related to that and I didn't know how else to explain it. Thanks for your help I will investigate those tools but it seems that it is what I am looking for. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It is un-clear how your driver gets instantiated and killed, but the most theoretical answer is to do a Driver.Quit only after all your tests have executed.